# Rails: call model-methods (with ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, methods, model, call

my question is, what's the rails-way to call a method over ajax. Let's start with a quote

> REST is about Path and Verb
>   ([github.com/JumpstartLab/curriculum/](https://github.com/JumpstartLab/curriculum/blob/master/source/projects/blogger.markdown#rest-is-about-path-and-verb))

I have a method that does operations on my nested-list. Problem: How to call it over ajax when the user clicks on a link? Or at all. In Rails.

```
class NestedList < ActiveRecord::Base

 def someListOperation # should be called when user clicks something
   ...
 end

end
```

Do you

1. Put a switch-block into, say, the #update action to decide if and what method(s) to call? Then one would pass the method-name along with the required parameters ?
2. Make a route just for the method ?
3. Some special third option only available through ajax-magic

In <1> you would for instance `link_to` (or other ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper ) the *update-url* with `method: :patch`, while in <2> you would point it to some custom url like `/nested-list/move-up/:id`

Where do you generally put the logic that is not simply about updating *data-fields*. That's about ***doing something*** on user-action ( `$('a').bind('click', function() {...}` ). And what's the proper rails-way to invoke these model-methods. Following MVC such logic should go to the *model*, right? Because most examples (with or without ajax) only deal with updating data-fields 1-to-1 as the data comes from the form.

Thank you, Spotz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will have to add a controller action with its corresponding route. A quick example would be:

**config/routes.rb:**

```
patch "/nested-list/move_up/:id" => "nested_lists#move_up", as: :move_up_nested_list
```

Then on your nested lists controller:

**app/controllers/nested_lists_controller.rb:**

```
def move_up
 @nested_list = NestedList.find(params[:id])
 @nested_list.someListOperation

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to some_path_you_want_to_redirect }
  format.js
 end
end
```

Now you have your controller action responding to both, html(which is default) and javascript, on your view you can just add a `link_to` like so:

**some/view.html.erb:**

```
link_to "Move up", move_up_nested_list_path(nested_list), method: :patch, remote: true
```

The only thing missing is you will have to add a js response view, in case you want to update the DOM, something like:

**app/views/nested_lists/move_up.js.erb**

```
//Your javascript code
```

Comment: Thanks

I created a route/action to move a node 1) „horizontally” and 2) „vertically” up/down and additionally pass a value for the :direction which is handled by a case-statement.

Answer (score 0):

The way that makes the most sense to make is making a route and controller method just for that action. So'd you'd have a route and controller method with a verb corresponding to what the user did, and then that controller method would interact with the model.